# Exception while trying to set up DotNetNuke content localization

Tags: localization, translation, dotnetnuke

I was trying to set the DotNetNuke Content localization, but when I click on enable localized content on language page the progress bar that show up stuck.

I was checking the event log and i noticed that it raises a general exception:

> DefaultDataProvider: DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider,
>   DotNetNuke.SqlDataProvider ExceptionGUID:
>   a139c600-71a0-4ee3-a66f-5968bd2bdfde InnerException: Transaction
>   (Process ID 56) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process
>   and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
>   FileName: FileLineNumber: 0 FileColumnNumber: 0 Method:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError StackTrace: Message:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 56) was
>   deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen
>   as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlConnection
>   connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText,
>   SqlParameter[] commandParameters) at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   connectionString, CommandType commandType, String commandText,
>   SqlParameter[] commandParameters) at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   connectionString, String spName, Object[] parameterValues) at
>   DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.AddSearchItemWordPosition(Int32
>   SearchItemWordID, String ContentPositions) at
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Search.SearchDataStore.AddIndexWords(Int32
>   indexId, SearchItemInfo searchItem, String language) at
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Search.SearchDataStore.StoreSearchItems(SearchItemInfoCollection
>   SearchItems)

It should localize pages in three languages, pt-BR(Main), en-US and es-ES. But it only works on en-US. It succefully localize all the pages in en-US but in es-ES it just does the first page.

Now anytime i try to do some page related activities, as adding a page in the 3 languages, the pages gets bugged and keep rising exceptions when i'm trying to edit it. And the page doesn't show up in es-ES language, only in pt and en. This elimineted all workaround that i could think and couldnt find any solution on web.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the search engine scheduler for DotNetNuke. Disable the scheduler, or increasing the time between scheduler activity to avoid concurrent updates. See this thread. http://forums.asp.net/t/905236.aspx/1